# Dual booted Ubuntu 15.10/Win10 - Is it possible to add folder shortcuts from Win partition?

Tags: dual-boot

I hope I am explaining this well enough to be understood!

My entire disk already auto-mounts, which I believe is a default function. What I would like to find out is if specific folders from within the Windows partition of the drive can be accessed and auto-mounted when Ubuntu starts? Ideally, I would prefer to add them to the Unity Launcher or Dash somewhere.

Is this doable? THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something like that, I suppose. Do you see the bar on the left side of your File Manager? You can easily add folders to it.

Go to Menu>Bookmarks>Bookmarks...

Then, proceed to add a new bookmark(the process is intuitive: click (+), select location, and add)

Since your partitions automatically mount, it won't be any problem at all. But remember, if the partitions aren't mounted for any reason, the bookmarks won't work(it will show an error).

About adding them to Launcher/Dash:

When you right click on Files, you will see the bookmark you added. Click on it to open.

Does this fit your needs?